# ADF Monitor Column Order drag not working

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory V2, When we go to Monitor->Trigger runs/ Pipeline runs->Edit Columns as given below and try to drag and change order, nothing happens. Is there any other settings for this ?

[image]

Comment: what't your purpose?That's the feature Data Factory provides us to customize  view of these pipeline details table.. There's isn't an other settings for this.

Comment: I want to change the order. It is not working

Comment: Hi @Blue Clouds, we need firstly delete the column, then add and reset the order, that works. Please ref my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tested and also found that we can't set the column order by drag and drop a field if all the columns are set already. But it can be solved by this solution:

Please delete these columns firstly and add again to set the column order:

[image]

Reset the column order and save:

[image]

For example I set the new column order like this:

[image]

Manage Overview:

[image]

HTH.

Comment: this is work around. The promised drag functionality is not working.

Comment: @BlueClouds yes, I think that should be posted as a new feedback. Hope the product team can fix it.

Comment: I found that once you come out of the page the functionality is lost. or if the page is refreshed.

Comment: Hi @BlueClouds, thanks, I tested and have the same result. For your question, we can use the way to set the column order as you want. But about why we can't keep these column order after page refreshed, that's maybe by a design issue and extension question. We are the user like you and can't give the answer. Like I said, you could add the new feedback here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory.  We can help you vote it to make Data Factory product team see it.

Comment: @BlueClouds can you accept my answer? What we can do is provide more workarounds or solution for you, according our experience. Thanks again.

Comment: posted https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/43079832-adf-dasboard-column-order-cannot-be-changed

Comment: Hi @BlueClouds, I have help you voted it. Please check it.